# HAproxy 503 No server is available to handle this request

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, haproxy

HAproxy is configured in a load balancer server. When both the server are failed it shows

> 503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this
>   request.Error

How to configure HAproxy redirect another server only when both server failed.

Comment: can you please elaborate. You have a 3 node HA setup?

Comment: 3 node means three server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to redirect to a 3rd server :

```
backend bk_postfix
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:whatever (should be a valid check)
  server server1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 check
  server server1 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80 check
  server server2 zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:80 check backup
```

the "backup" flag will enable the 3rd server only if the health checks have failed on your active machines, thus redirecting traffic to it.